# Next.js does not recognize custom npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Here's my personal custom package structure:

```
package.json
Posts.js
```

And here's the content of `Posts.js`:

```
const Posts = () => {
    return <div>List of posts</div>
}

export default Posts;
```

I publish this to my GitHub Package Registry and I install it to a next.js app using `npm install @myOwnerName:blog`.

And I can verify that it's been installed.

However, when I want to use it using `import Posts from '@myOwnerName/blog/Posts'`, I see this error:

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/@myOwnerUser/blog/Posts.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const Posts = () => {
>     return <div>List of posts</div>
| }
|
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're package has been built / compiled?

Comment: @Lissy93, I have no idea what you mean. Why should I build/compile a single simple react component? Can't next.js simply reuse a component in its raw form?

Comment: Because that's not a js file even though it's file name has been mislabeled with a `.js` extension. That's a jsx file and jsx is a language invented by Facebook for their React.js project. JSX is not javascript though it can be compiled into javascript.

Comment: I haven't used Next much but if Next can import jsx code (React components) maybe it's just confused by the file extension. Try renaming the file with a `.jsx` extension. This usually works for me in React

Answer (score 0):

Before publish npm package, we should compile react components to `es-module`.
So, in webpack configuration, unknown file type error.
I think, it is more correct way to compile react component before publish it.